# In predicate logic, is it possible to distribute quantifiers

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

Is possible to establish that $\forall x \,\exists y\,(Fx \rightarrow Gy)$ is logically equal to $\forall x\,Fx \rightarrow \exists y\,Gy$?

If it does not work, why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on whether you mean $\;(\forall x\,Fx) \rightarrow \exists y\,Gy\;$ or $\;\forall x\,(Fx \rightarrow \exists y\,Gy)\;$.

The original expression is equivalent to the latter, but not to the former.

Here is a proof, using a sightly different notation, in tiny baby steps:
\begin{align}
& \langle \forall x :: \langle \exists y :: F(x) \Rightarrow G(y) \rangle \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"rewrite $\;p \Rightarrow q\;$ to $\;\lnot p \lor q\;$ -- the latter is usually easier to manipulate"} \\
& \langle \forall x :: \langle \exists y :: \lnot F(x) \lor G(y) \rangle \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"$\;\lor\;$ distributes over $\;\exists\;$"} \\
& \langle \forall x :: \langle \exists y :: \lnot F(x) \rangle \lor \langle \exists y :: G(y) \rangle \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"leave out quantification over variable $\;y\;$ which does not occur in $\;\lnot F(x)\;$"} \\
& \langle \forall x :: \lnot F(x) \lor \langle \exists y :: G(y) \rangle \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"reintroduce $\;\Rightarrow\;$ -- to achieve our goal"} \\
& \langle \forall x :: F(x) \Rightarrow \langle \exists y :: G(y) \rangle \rangle \\
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to distribute the quantifiers, but the result with the formula $∀x∃y(Fx→Gy)$ is not what you have suggested.

I'll use Enderton's system (see Herbert Enderton, [A Mathematical Introduction to Logic](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0122384520) (2nd - 2001)).

We need some provable equivalences [see Enderton, page 121 and page 130] :

> **(Q2A)** -- $\vdash (\alpha \rightarrow \forall x \beta) \leftrightarrow \forall x (\alpha \rightarrow \beta)$, if $x$ does not occur free in $\alpha$
>
> **(Q2B)** -- $\vdash (\alpha \rightarrow \exists x \beta) \leftrightarrow \exists x (\alpha \rightarrow \beta)$, if $x$ does not occur free in $\alpha$
>
> **(Q3A)** -- $\vdash (\forall x \beta \rightarrow \alpha) \leftrightarrow \exists x (\beta \rightarrow \alpha)$, if $x$ does not occur free in $\alpha$
>
> **(Q3B)** -- $\vdash (\exists x \beta \rightarrow \alpha) \leftrightarrow \forall x (\beta \rightarrow \alpha)$, if $x$ does not occur free in $\alpha$.

Starting with :

> $∀x∃y(Fx \rightarrow Gy)$

we apply first **(Q2B)**, because $y$ is not free in $Fx$, to get :

> $∀x(Fx \rightarrow ∃yGy)$.

Then we apply **(Q2A)**, because $x$ is not free in $∃yGy$, to get :

> > $∃xFx \rightarrow ∃yGy$.

This formula is clearly **not** equivalent to : $∀xFx \rightarrow ∃yGy$.

Answer (score 0):

It is not equivalent. If you just read what the statements are saying it should be clear. The statement

$\displaystyle \forall x\ \exists y\ (f(x) \rightarrow g(y))$

says that for every $x$ there exists some $y$ such that the statement $f(x) \rightarrow g(y)$ is true. The statement

$(\forall x\ f(x)) \rightarrow (\exists y\ g(y))$

says that if $f(x)$ is true for every $x$, then there exists a $y$ for which $g(y)$ is true. Hence the proprositional functions that you need to satisfy are different

Answer (score 0):

You could get the following
$\forall x (Fx\rightarrow \exists y Gy)$.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach to show they aren't equivalent is to exhibit a countermodel:

The latter statement -- assuming you mean $(\forall x Fx)\to \exists y Gy$ -- is true in a model where there's an F and a non-F, but nothing is G. But the former statement -- $\forall x\exists y(Fx\to Gy)$ -- is false in such a model.